# How can install and run a Qt program without Qt creator?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I made a media player using Qt creator.Now,I want to use it without Qt creator i.e., I want the users to use it without the help of Qt creator.How can I do that?

Comment: So what you're asking is how to deploy applications? Did [Qt's documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment.html) on the subject not provide any help? If you used it and got stuck, you should be asking about the specific problem you encountered when trying to follow those steps, instead of a general, generic question, which is off-topic for this site. if you didn't read the documentation, read it, and then ask here if you have any problems.

Comment: Did you build your program for "release", or just "debug"?

Comment: _How can I do that?_ By running the executable file. If you want a more helpful answer provide some clarifications on what exactly you want to know.

Comment: I am sorry.I am new to Qt.I just ran it on my PC to make sure it worked on my PC.I just debug I think @Makketronix

Answer (score 0):

You could use Travis CI to build it for Linux and OS X.
Here is an example configuration: https://github.com/pbek/QOwnNotes/blob/develop/.travis.yml
Here is the building done: https://travis-ci.org/pbek/QOwnNotes/builds

And you can use Appveyor to build it for Windows.
Again an example configuration:
https://github.com/pbek/QOwnNotes/blob/develop/appveyor.yml
Here is the building done: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/pbek/qownnotes/history

By using these two services you can create builds every time you commit/push to your git repository. I automatically create releases every time I push to the master branch.

I hope this helps.